# Android: How to not publish an app to Google Play and still be able to let others easily install and test the app?

Tags: android, testing, export, publish

I created a small Android project during my free time, and I decided to give a group of people I specifically know of to try the app out. The group of people created a forum community where everyone gathers around to share some of their own projects. They usually upload their programs written in C++, Java, C#, and sometimes give out tips to newcomers.

I wrote an app that does bitmap manipulation stuffs, and was hoping that others can easily test the app out without having to go through Google Play market. I just don't want my app to go entirely public to anyone in the market.

I told them that I am going to upload an Android app so they can check my project out. I understood that they are all not Android developers, so they haven't seen anyone in the community upload an Android app onto the forums yet.

So, I started to do a little research on this.

I thought about exporting the project as an unsigned Android app, but a Google search made me realize that unsigned Android app can't be installed onto an Android phone, even with "Unknown sources - Allow installation of non-Market apps" ticked in the Settings -> Security menu.

Another way I tried to do is to self-sign the application. I give the app 1 year before the certification is invalid, signed the app by using the Eclipse -> Export Android application wizard. I uploaded the app, and got notified by one of the group of people that the app can't be installed onto their phone.

This is where I am stuck and now I'm clearly in need of assistence. Is there a way you can upload an Android app onto a forum, let another user download the APK file, and install it onto their phone with no hassle? Just want to keep this testing session in private, if it matters.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you had a look at my suggested answer?

Comment: Yes I did. I told the owner of an Android phone, who was downloading my unsigned APK, about this and the solution provided, and the owner said something about not being able to install. He said he'll reply back once he find anything. So, I begin waiting for the owner's feedback to this moment.

Comment: ok. If he can't install, it may be because he/she has a previous version that was signed with a different key (i.e, not a debug key) installed.

Comment: Does this mean I need to self-sign the APK no matter what in order to get it installed on Android? Because I gave the owner an unsigned APK. I didn't use the debug key nor did I create a new key.

Comment: An unsigned apk uses the debug key under the hood as far as I know. Giving an unsigned APK is fine. You just can't install it over a signed APK, and vice versa. i.e. if they already had a version, it's safer if they uninstall the older version before installing the new one

Comment: Ok. I'll ask them again. Regardless of the outcome, I think this wraps up everything I asked for. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easy way that I use to let users download and test an app is to ask them to do this:

Settings -> Applications -> Unknown Sources -> Tick the Check box

Then export an unsigned APK of your app and make it available to them. An easy way is to upload the APK to dropbox or host it on your website or to just email the file to them. Once they've downloaded the APK, they can just open it and it will install and run.

Answer (score 0):

You can install an unsigned APK file if you tick the option in Settings -> Security menu.

Answer (score 0):

You can upload your apk to GP as alpha-version, publish it and allow test for this peoples.

They will can download this app from GP.